How to block message submission on "Enter" in a Chrome extension until message verification is complete?
I'm developing a Chrome extension that intercepts user messages before they are sent to the ChatGPT API. The goal is to verify whether a message contains sensitive content before it's sent. I want to prevent the message from being sent when the user presses the "Enter" key until the verification process is completed.
Here is the current flow I'm trying to achieve:

The user types or pastes a message and presses "Enter."
The Chrome extension intercepts the "Enter" key press and blocks the message from being sent immediately.
The extension verifies whether the message contains sensitive content.
If the message doesn't contain sensitive data, it is allowed to proceed, and the message is sent.
If the message contains sensitive content, it is blocked, and the user is notified.

Current Problem:
Issue 1: When the "Enter" key is pressed, the message is sent to ChatGPT without waiting for my sensitive content verification.
Issue 2: Even if the message contains sensitive content, it still gets through and is sent to ChatGPT.
Issue 3: The textarea is reset after pressing Enter, which I want to prevent if the message is blocked.
Content.ts
function addEventListeners (
  textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement | null,
  button: HTMLButtonElement | null
): void {
  textarea?.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    void (async () => {
      if (event.isTrusted && event.code === 'Enter' && !event.shiftKey) {
        // Stop the event from propagating
        event.stopPropagation()
        event.preventDefault()
        
        const proceed = await shouldProceed(textarea)
        if (proceed) {
          button?.click()
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ detections: 0 })
        }
      }
    })()
  })

  textarea?.addEventListener('input', () => {
    void (async () => {
      const triggeredDetectors = await countTriggeredDetectorsWrapper(textarea)
      setExtensionBadge(triggeredDetectors)
    })()
  })

  button?.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    void (async () => {
      if (event.isTrusted) {
        event.stopPropagation()
        event.preventDefault()
        
        const proceed = await shouldProceed(textarea)
        if (proceed) {
          button?.click()
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ detections: 0 })
        }
      }
    })()
  })
}

Issues:

When the user presses "Enter," the message gets sent directly to ChatGPT before verifying if it contains sensitive content.
The message should not be sent if it contains sensitive content.
I want to stop the message submission and verify it before any submission happens.

What I've tried:

Preventing default behavior: I use event.preventDefault() to stop the form submission when "Enter" is pressed, but the message still gets sent.

Asynchronous verification: I added the shouldProceed() function to check if the message is safe. However, it doesn't seem to work as expected because the message is still sent even before the verification completes.


Expected Behavior:

When the user presses "Enter," the message should not be sent immediately.
The content of the message should be checked for sensitive data before it is allowed to send to ChatGPT.
If sensitive content is detected, the message should be blocked from sending.
If no sensitive content is detected, the message should proceed.

Any suggestions on how to properly intercept and block the message from being sent until the verification process is complete?

You can override window.fetch and/or XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send in the MAIN world (see these and these examples). As the main link explains, your override will use externally_connectable messaging or CustomEvent with a second content script to relay the messages to the extension's background script.

in which scenario are you suggesting can you please clear it

Your post contains several indicators that ChatGPT or another LLM was used to generate it. For a variety of reasons, the use of such generative AI tools is strictly disallowed on Stack Overflow. Please edit your question to remove and replace content that was generated using these tools.

Focus your question: if you're asking about how to intercept user input in an extension, that's what you're asking about, and almost none of the code you're showing is relevant. Reduce it all the way down to a [mcve], and then only show that. After seaching the web (including SO) specifically for that one, particular problem. SO is not for getting your entire codebase reviewed, it's for getting well-phrased questions about a single problem answered, not just for yourself but for all future visitors.

check updated code
